# Add comma at end of all lines except 1 , 2, 3 and last line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am trying to add comma at end of all lines except line 1 , 2, 3 and last time.
I tried using sed to achieve it:

```
sed '$![1 2 3 s/,/' filename
```

but this is not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the address range `1,3` to exclude the first three lines from adding the comma, then remove the comma from the last line ($ in the address).

```
sed '1,3!s/$/,/;$s/,$//'
```

Comment: Perl version, just for fun: `perl -ne 's/$/,/ unless (1 .. 3) || eof'`

Comment: very clean. There is only one exception where this will fail : if the file is only 1,2,3 lines long and the last line has a `,` at the end. `sed '1,3{$q};1,3!s/$/,/;$s/,$//'` should fix this.

Comment: @melpomene should be `-pe`... also another way of doing the same is `perl -pe 's/$/,/ if $. > 3 && !eof'`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to skip those lines using the `b` command

```
$ # GNU version: sed '1,3b; $b; s/$/,/'
$ seq 7 | sed -e '1,3b' -e '$b' -e 's/$/,/'
1
2
3
4,
5,
6,
7
```

From [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list)

> **b label** Branch unconditionally to label. The label may be omitted, in
>   which case the next cycle is started.

And a `perl` version

```
$ seq 7 | perl -pe 's/$/,/ if $. > 3 && !eof'
1
2
3
4,
5,
6,
7
```

- `$.` contains line number, `eof` checks if it is last line